# Multi-platform web service

Tags: web-services, rest, embedded, windows-ce, mqx

I don't have much experience in the web-server/service world, so excuse my question if it is trivial.

I have an embedded device that supports wifi.
Currently the device runs WinCE, but in the future this device will be running a Real-Time OS (MQX).

What I want to be able to do is from a client application sync to this device wirelessly and send simple HTTP Post/Get calls with XML data, and then have the device be able to respond back to that call.

Does any framework/code come to mind that can easily help me achieve these goals?

Comment: One option that seems to be what I am looking for is: [Barracuda Server](http://barracudaserver.com)

Comment: Um, Windows CE *is* a real-time OS...

Comment: I wasn't implying that it WinCE is not a RTOS...I was just saying that in the future we will be moving from WinCE to MQX.